# Как сделать перемешивание массива с последующим восстановлением исходного порядка?

Tags: php, javascript, сортировка

Есть задача «запутывая данных» при передаче от сервера (php) к клиенту (js).
Применять шифрование типа aes не вижу смысла. Так как все равно ключ можно вытянуть из js.

Есть массив  c данными на php, нужно его перемешать по какому-то неслучайному алгоритму.

```
$array = [‘asdasd’, ‘egegerg’, ‘qwdqwdqwdq’, ‘2’, ‘wqdqwdqd’];
```

После на клиенте в js мы должны принять эти данные, сделать обратную сортировку и получить оригинальный массив

```
var array = [‘asdasd’, ‘egegerg’, ‘qwdqwdqwdq’, ‘2’, ‘wqdqwdqd’];
```

Как это лучше сделать? По чем сортировать, чтобы потом выполнить обратную операцию? Сортировка по алфавиту или просто перевернуть массив не подходит.

Comment: А какой в этом смысл, если на клиенте все равно будет алгоритм в открытом доступе?

Comment: Привет. Если кто-то сильно захочет, то получил в любом случае. Вопрос в том чтобы усложнить эту задачу. Js код у меня запутан через https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator .

Comment: Ну не совсем в любом случае, все же можно использовать различные ЭЦП на клиенте, да даже тот же AES, проосто ключ делать не общий, а спрашивать у пользователя) Но опять же - от кого защищаетесь? От пользователя или что бы сторонние приложение не могли использовать ваши данные?

Comment: От сторонних приложений. Чтобы нельзя было просто взять и спарсить. У меня это уже работает на aes. Проблема в том что ключ можно найти в коде js. Также данные в 1 мегабайт дешифруется в aes почти секунду.

Comment: дак вы ключ частями передайте тогда. какая разница части массива восстанавливать или ключа.

Comment: Мне кажется, использование алгоритма перемешивания совсем не усложнит взлом ваших данных. Разве что вы будете обновлять\изменять алгоритм вручную каждый день\неделю\месяц, что бы стороннии приложения устали вас ломать))

Answer (score 0):

**Произвольное перемешивание массива туда и обратно**

Как это приблизительно делается я покажу на примере JavaScript, а вы уже сами для PHP напишите по этому примеру.

```js
//НАЧАЛО СЕРВЕРНОЙ ЧАСТИ
function shuffle(arr)
{
 var newArr = arr.slice(0); //copy array

    for(var counter = newArr.length; counter--; )
 {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (counter + 1)),
   tmp = newArr[counter];

        newArr[counter] = newArr[index];
        newArr[index] = tmp;
    }

    return newArr
}

var array =
 [ 
  'p0', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4',
  'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9',
  'p10', 'p11', 'p12', 'p13', 'p14'
 ],
 trueIndexes = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
 trueIndexes.push(i);

//keyForClient - index-ы для обратного перемещения
var keyForClient = [],
 newArrayForClient = [],
 //Если, к примеру shuffledIndexes[0] -> 2 означает, что 'p0' перемещается на index = 2
 shuffledIndexes = shuffle(trueIndexes);

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
 newArrayForClient[shuffledIndexes[i]] = array[i];
 keyForClient[i] = shuffledIndexes.indexOf(trueIndexes[i])
}

//КОНЕЦ СЕРВЕРНОЙ ЧАСТИ

//После этого newArrayForClient и keyForClient передаются клиенту

console.log(newArrayForClient.join(', '));
console.log(keyForClient.join(', '));
console.log('--------------------');

//КЛИЕНТСКАЯ ЧАСТЬ:

var trueArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < newArrayForClient.length; i++)
 trueArray[keyForClient[i]] = newArrayForClient[i];

//Для проверки:
console.log(trueArray.join(', '));
```

Это не более чем ответ на вопрос «Как выполнить необычную сортировку/перемешивание».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но это не то что мне нужно. Вы предлагаете просто сделать перемешивание и сохранить ключи и передавать новый масив + ключи. Мне нужен алгоритм сортировки при котором между клиентом передается только массив. Порядок сортировки неслучайный и четко заложен а алгоритм и на клиенте и на сервере.